# What are the downsides of using bootstrap in plugin development?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, widgets, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use twitter-bootstrap in my plugin. Are there any downsides of that? Will it create any issue if other plugin are already using the same on WordPress environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are clearly challenges to using such a public dependency as Bootstrap, especially in a public plugin:

- version conflicts;
- styling conflicts;
- script conflicts.

To minimize possibility of conflict and breakage you would need to consider following extra steps:

1. Importing *just* the necessary Bootstrap styles into your stylesheet and making them specific to *only* markup related to your plugin.
2. Only load JS scripts from Bootstrap that you need and putting them in `noConflict` mode, which will keep them out of global namespace and remap them so that only your plugin will make use of that specific instance.